# $\int_{x}^{x+1} |f(y)| dy \le C$ with an $C > 0$ for all $x > 0$, prove that $\sup\limits_{0 < y} |f(y)|$ exists

Tags: real-analysis

It is $\int_{x}^{x+1} |f(y)| dy \le C$ with an $C > 0$ for all $x > 0$.

It is obvious that $\sup\limits_{0 < y} |f(y)|$ exists, but how can I formally prove it?

I know that $\int_{x}^{x+1} |f(y)| dy \le \sup\limits_{x \le y \le x+1} |f(y)|$ holds for all $x > 0$, but how can I prove, that $\sup\limits_{x \le y \le x+1} |f(y)|$ is bounded, too?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
n^2(x-2n) &\text{ when }& 2n\le x<2n+1/n \\
2n-n^2(x-2n) &\text{ when }& 2n+1/n\le x<2n+2/n \\
0 &\text{ when }& 2n+2/n\le x<2n+2 \\
\end{cases}$$

Then it is a counterexample, as 
$$ 2n\le x \le 2n+2 \\\implies
\int_x^{x+1} f(x) dx \le
\int_{2n}^{2n+4} f(x)dx =
2\times \frac12 \times \frac 1n\times n 
+ 2\times \frac12 \times \frac 1{n+1}\times (n+1) = 2
$$and 
$$
\sup_{x\in[2n,2n+2]} |f(x)| = n^2\times \frac 1n = n
$$

Comment: Is this function defined for all $x > 0$? With $n = 1$ I dont see which function value $x = 5$ would get

Comment: for $x=5$, use the value $n=2$ so that $2n < 5 < 2n+2$

Answer (score 0):

Take $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$. It is integrable in every unit interval inside $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, with this integral bounded, but without a bounded value.

Comment: could I prove it with $x > 0$ and $x$ as an integer?

Comment: I did not understand, could you precise?

Comment: I assume $x > 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Yes, if is valid for every $x>0$ at so, also valid for $x\in \mathbb{N}$